# Julia iteratively make 3D array from 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

I am trying to make a 3D array from many 2D arrays.

> **Image Files**
>
> Each image becomes a 2D array.
>
> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xBucvqhKFjAfbRIhq5wjr40kSjNor_0t?usp=sharing

```
using Images, Colors

paths = readdir(
    "/Users/me/Downloads/ct_scans"
    , join = true
)

images_3D = []

for p = paths
    img = load(p)
    gray = Gray.(img)
    arr = convert(Array{Float64}, gray) # <----- 2D array
    append!(images_3d, arr)
end


>>> size(images_3d) 
(1536000) # <--- 1D view? 

>>> 1536000 == 80*160*120 
true

>>> reshaped_3d = reshape(images_3d, (80,160,120))

>>> Gray.(reshaped_3d[1,:,:])
# 160x120 scrambled mess of pixels not rearranged as expected
```

- `append!` makes a size== 1D array that does not reshape as expected.
- Whereas `push!` creates an array of hard arrays that keep their shape. It’s not technically 3D, just an 80 element vector.
- When I tried to initialize an empty 3D and then overwrite each 2D with my own 2D image I got `Matrix{Float64} to Float64` type conversion failures.
- Can’t iteratively `vcat` 2D arrays because cannot overwrite variables.

Part of the reason for posting this is to see how Julia programmers approach multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this, you'll have to tty and test which one is the best in your case.

#### with append! and resize

`Array`s in Julia should start iterating with the first index, which the number of images is the last index. If 80 is the amount of images, the `reshape` should be
`reshape(images_3d, (160,120,80))`
(maybe exchange 120 and 160, not sure about this one).

And then to get the first image, it's `reshaped_3d[:,:,1]`

#### with push!

`push!`ing the matrices and then creating the 3d array with `cat` would work too :

```
julia> A = [rand(3,4) for i in 1:2];

julia> cat(A..., dims=3)
3×4×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.372747  0.17654   0.398272  0.231992
 0.514789  0.342374  0.399816  0.277959
 0.908909  0.864676  0.9788    0.585375

[:, :, 2] =
 0.358169  0.816448  0.0558052  0.404178
 0.747453  0.80815   0.384903   0.447053
 0.314895  0.46264   0.947465   0.170982
```

### initialize the 3D Array (probably the best one)

and fill it up progressively

```
julia> A = Array{Float64}(undef,3,4,2);

julia> for i in 1:2
           A[:,:,i] = rand(3,4)
       end

julia> A
3×4×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.478106  0.829818  0.526572  0.644238
 0.714812  0.781246  0.93239   0.759864
 0.523958  0.955136  0.70079   0.193489

[:, :, 2] =
 0.481405   0.561407  0.184557    0.449584
 0.547769   0.170311  0.371797    0.538843
 0.0285712  0.731686  0.00126473  0.452273
```

Comment: I would especially recommend the last one (preallocate array and fill it) since this is usually going to be both the most efficient, and it will usually give clear errors if you have made a mistake with the dimensions

Comment: Thank you. Making *n/samples* the last dimension allowed for the 2D matrix to overwrite the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the accepted answer, looping over the first index will be even faster. Consider the following two functions, `test1()` is faster to run because the loop is in the first index.

```
aa_stack1 = zeros(3, 10000, 10000);
aa_stack3 = zeros(10000, 10000, 3);

function test1()
    for ii = 1:3
        aa_stack1[ii, :, :] = rand(10000, 10000)
    end
end

function test2()
    for ii = 1:3
        aa_stack3[:, :, ii] = rand(10000, 10000)
    end
end

@time test1()
@time test2()
```

The first way "maximizes memory locality and reduces cache misses" because "when you iterate over the first dimension, the values of the other two dimensions are kept in cache, which means that accessing them takes less time" (according to ChatGPT).